# Filter looker tile to show last 7 reported days in dataset?

Tags: data-visualization, filtering, visualization, looker

How do I filter down to the last 7 "REPORTED" days in a dataset.

Simply filtering the last 7 days will not work as the reported days are not always consecutive.
I cannot use something like last 10 days to catch them because I need to limit the set to 7.

Say I have a date column in my dataset that looks like this:

```
COMPLETED_DATE:

05/09/2022
05/06/2022
05/05/2022
05/04/2022
05/03/2022
04/20/2022
04/18/2022
04/17/2022
04/16/2022
```

I need looker to display the results related to the last 7 reported dates like this:

```
COMPLETED_DATE:

05/09/2022
05/06/2022
05/05/2022
05/04/2022
05/03/2022
04/20/2022
04/18/2022
```

Is this something I can do with the built in filters or will I need to write some LookML to get this done?

I am guessing I might be able to write a dimension to do this. I found online a dimension for filtering on last date. I am not sure how I can reword this to filter on last 7 days.

```
dimension: latest_date { type: yesno sql: ${created_date} = max(${created_date}) ;; }
```

[Source](https://community.looker.com/technical-tips-tricks-1021/how-to-filter-on-the-last-day-with-available-data-27066)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by editing the query data to include a RANKED row.
This lets us filter on the rank based on this column.

This was worked out over a few replies on the looker forums here:

[how-to-filter-on-last-7-available-dates](https://community.looker.com/sql-10/how-to-filter-on-last-7-available-dates-29962#post55230)

MY solution was as follows:

Turns out removing the “partition by portion” fixed the count issue.
I removed it after seeing an error that said the `ORDER_BY` was required with the OVER clause and for some reason that prompted me to check what it would say if I removed the `PARTITION BY` portion. For whatever reason the counts are showing up now using `ROW_NUMBER` and `RANK` without issue.

```
Select received_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY received_date DESC) from
(SELECT distinct CAST(received_time as DATE) received_date FROM TABLE_NAME) s
WHERE received_date <= '2022-04-12'
ORDER BY received_date  DESC
```

AND

```
Select received_date, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY received_date DESC) from
(SELECT distinct CAST(received_time as DATE) received_date FROM TABLE_NAME) s
WHERE received_date <= '2022-04-12'
ORDER BY received_date  DESC
```

Both results in:

```
received_date   RANK
2022-04-12      1
2022-04-11      2
2022-04-10      3
2022-04-08      4
2022-04-07      5
2022-04-06      6
2022-04-05      7
```

As you can see I get the count I was looking for as we do not have a 04-09 date in the available dates and the count moves on to the next date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without needing to change LookML:

- Create an Explore and sort by `COMPLETED_DATE`
- Create an auxiliary *Table Calculation* called `rank`, and define it as `max(row()) - row() + 1`. This column will count the report numbers from most recent to oldest
- Create a filter to display only reports with a `rank` less than or equal to the desired number of reports

Answer (score -1):

You have two approaches based on what you know about the reported dates.

1.

- If you know that the last reports would be at least X days ago => Filter your tile by "X days ago"
- Otherwise => No filter by date (query everything)

2. Order by date desc
3. Set the row limit to 7

Comment: This is not going to work. I need all records that correspond to the last 7 recorded dates. This could be hundreds of records so setting row limit to 7 is not a solution. And the entire point of needing a dynamic solution is the fact is we do not know the last report date. I already solved the problem buy editing the query to build the rank info using windows functions and then just ordering by rank in looker.